# JBoss upload and download

Tags: jboss, fs

I'm building an application which accepts a task as an input file, generates an output file and returns a link to download it. I'm using JBoss as application server and Struts 2 as MVC framework. My questions are:

1. Which directory should I use for storing uploaded files?
2. How should I configure JBoss to allow downloading files from that folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in several ways.

If file size is small you can just save it in application memory. It depends how many files and how much memory you've got.

If app memory is no good for that you can create temporary files (Temporary files location are determined by OS. You can get temp location by this method `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");`)

To download files you dont need to configure JBoss. Create some Servlet which reads file from FileSystem and writes fileData (byte array) to Servlet's output stream.

Here are links [how to create temporary file](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-temporary-file-in-java/) and [How to write data to temporary file](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-data-to-temporary-file-in-java/)